# How to print a String defined in one class in a different class?

Tags: java, string, class

I have two classes. In the first one, I used the `Scanner` to retrieve the user's name and then store it in a `String` called `name`. Then say, I start a new class, and want to print that came out, how do I go about it. So I just wrote up this code as an example, so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to ask. I'll post both classes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class One {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;
        String start;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello, what is your name?");
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hello "+name+", welcome! To ocntinue, please hit any key.");
        start = input.nextLine();

        if(start != null){
            Two object = new Two();
        }

    }
}
```

Second class.

```
public class Two {
    public Two() {
        System.out.println("Ok "+One.name+", lets start!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass your value to the Two class `constructor`.

```
if(start != null){
        Two object = new Two(start );
    }
```

and

```
public Two(String  s){

    System.out.println("Ok "+s+", lets start!");

}
```

Comment: This worked when I changed "start" to "name" in the parenthesis for the class object, thanks!

Comment: @DanielSpeed  you are welcome :).Please mark it as answer if its helpful.

Answer (score 5):

So, you will probably be doing something like this: -

```
class One
{
  private String name = "bob";

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    One one = new One();
    Two two = new Two(one);

    // You could also just pass an r-value to Two, as in, Two(new One()) if you
    // never require 'one' again
  }
}

class Two
{
  public Two(One one)
  {
    System.out.println("Ok " + one.getName() + ", lets start!");
  }
}
```

**What is going on?**

1. Creating two classes in your `main` entry point method.
2. Passing the instance of `One` to the constructor of `Two`
3. Two then calls `getName()`

You could, as others have suggested, pass a string as the constructor; alternatively, you could do both if required as Java supports *overloading methods* see

**Recommendations**

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html for overriding methods so that you may see how to pass both a string and an object reference by value. What you are doing right now is passing the object reference of `one` by value. It may not be needed or you may want to provide restrictions using an interface, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: In your `Two` class constructor you're calling the `getName` method as static not from the `one` object.

Answer (score 2):

Use the constructor to pass the values

```
public class Two {

private String value;

public Two(String a){

  this.value=a;

    System.out.println("Ok "+value+", lets start!");

  }

 //getter and setters
}
```

Then while creating the instance use that constructor

```
 Two object = new Two(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compile, move the `String name` variable into a static field:

```
public class One {

    public static String name;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Note: The "name" variable is no longer defined here
        String start; // etc
        // rest of code the same
    }
}
```

I'm not going to tell you this is good code design, but it does what you asked.

Comment: I tried that myself, but then it throws an error and says to remove invalid modifiers, which then removed public and static and leaves me back at square 1 xD

Comment: NOTE: The field `String name` is defined BEFORE the main method - as a field of the class! See edit to answer that hopefully makes this clearer

Answer (score 0):

You will also do like this

```
public class One {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
     retrun this.name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String name;
        String start;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello, what is your name?");
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hello "+name+", welcome! To ocntinue, please hit any key.");
        start = input.nextLine();

        if(start != null){
            Two two = new Two();
            two.printName(this); 
        }

    }

    class Two{

           public void printName(One one){
            System.out.println("" + one.getName() );
           }

    }
```